# Why L' is not regular?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, regular-expressions, closure-properties

$$L'=\{ww|w\in L\}$$

I need to give an example of regular language L for which the concatenation of 2's $w$ gives $L'$ which is not regular.

How can I give such an example if according to closure properties for concatenation $L1L2$. each of them is regular,concatenation gives me a regular output.

Comment: The difference: You have to take the same w.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are having trouble distinguishing the difference between regular and non-regular languages, so I try to give a short explanation before I give you an example.

We call a language $L$ regular if it can be decided if a word is in the language with
an algorithm/a machine with constant (finite) memory by examining all symbols
in the word one after another. E.g. the language consisting just of the word $ab$ is
regular, as we can decide whether a word is in it without requiring arbitrary
amounts of memory; you just check whether the first symbol is $a$, whether the
second is $b$, and whether any more symbols follow. The construct of a finite-state machine is used to prove whether a language is regular or not.

So if we take $L_1 = \{a^nb \space | \space n \in \mathbb{N}\}$; this is a regular language as you don't need arbitrary amounts of memory, the concatenation $L_1' = \{  a^nba^nb \space | \space n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ would be non-regular as you need a memory to 'remember' how many $a$'s the first one has as the second $a$ is required to have the same amount.

Now as [gnasher729](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/17408/gnasher729) already stated, $L_2 = \{a^*b\}$ is regular and $L'_2 = \{ a^*ba^*b\}$ would also be regular as we do not have to remember how many $a$'s there are. We only need a finite-state machine to check if the last $a$ in each part is followed by one $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Let L = a*b. LL is regular ($a^nba^mb$). But the language you are asked to check is $a^nba^nb$ where the two n’s are the same. There are plenty of proofs in the last days here that you can adapt. And Myhill-Nerode is super easy.

Comment: I wonder how a characterization of L would look like such that L' is regular. Maybe it has be of the form L=v* for some word v?